# Tilestache does not work

Tags: tilestache

On a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install I followed the tutorial from here: http://proyectosbeta.net/2015/05/tilestache-en-ubuntu-14-10-desktop/

When I reach the part http://localhost/tiles/tiles.py/osm/preview.html the link give me 500 error.

What can be the problem?

Juliana

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the repository to the latest version?

https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache

Also, is there anything in your Apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I've been trying in various ways to get tilestache to work over the past month. I created a guide [here](https://gist.github.com/gabefair/49a5379511bfb65a25ab2c5e6b1c8816) of how I got some of it working.

I'm currently trying to get the vector.goodies to stop returning `known unknown!` errors